# How to use semaphores to ensure order when using Poco multi-threading?

Tags: c++, multithreading, semaphore, poco-libraries

I am writing a simple program to demonstrate the use of semaphores. (And later to test if custom wrote semaphores work).

I have 4 threads running a function concurrently. Each function wait's a random amount of time, and then prints: `Hello, world! This is thread` *n* `I slept for` *uS*`uS`.

As you would expect, the message's print to the standard output in a random order. This demonstrates that the threads are running concurrently since they would appear in order if they are executing sequentially.

I want to use a semaphore to force order in this demonstration. However, it currently does not work.

Here is my code:

```
sem = sem_open("mutex" , O_CREAT | O_RDWR , S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO, 1); // name, oflag, mode, initial value

Poco::Thread thread[5];

class HelloRunnable: public Poco::Runnable
{
public:
    HelloRunnable(int arg) //constructor for the runnable
    {
        n = arg;
    }

    int n;

    virtual void run() //entry point for the threads
    {
        sem_wait(sem); //the semaphore
            timeval t;
            gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
            srand(t.tv_usec * t.tv_sec);
            int uS = rand()%100000;
            usleep(uS); //sleep for random length of time

            std::cout << "Hello, world! This is thread " << n << " I slept for "<< uS << "uS" <<std::endl;
        sem_post(sem);
        return;
    }
};



int main()
{
    HelloRunnable runnable1(1); //construct a runnable with arg = 1
    thread[1].start(runnable1); //execute that runnable

    HelloRunnable runnable2(2); //construct a runnable with arg = 2
    thread[2].start(runnable2); //execute that runnable

    HelloRunnable runnable3(3); //...
    thread[3].start(runnable3);

    HelloRunnable runnable4(4);
    thread[4].start(runnable4);

    //wait for all threads to finish
    thread[1].join();
    thread[2].join();
    thread[3].join();
    thread[4].join();

    return 0;
}
```

However, the threads still print the message to the standard output in a random order. For example:

```
//Hello, world! This is thread 2 I slept for 15001uS
//Hello, world! This is thread 1 I slept for 51124uS
//Hello, world! This is thread 4 I slept for 60884uS
//Hello, world! This is thread 3 I slept for 86137uS
```

Where in the code should I place the semaphore so that it ensures the messages are printed in order? Apologies if this is simple. I do not come from a coding background.

**EDIT**

I moved the `sem_wait` to just before the `usleep`. Now it works better, but not all of the time. It prints in order about %45 of the time, in reverse order about 45%, and in a random order about %10 of the time. Why is this!?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that threads blocked in **sem_wait** are waked up in unpredictable order. Moreover you add some random sleep time adding more disorder.

In fact, you need one semaphore per thread.
Thread *n* should **sem_post** semaphore *n + 1* then **sem_wait** semaphore *n*.
Last thread should **sem_post** semaphore *0* and so on.
Simply create your semaphores in one array, the first one with initial value 1 and the other 0. The thread argument can be the index to access the right semaphore in thread.

```
#include <Poco/Thread.h>

#include <iostream>

#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define THREADS 5
#define LOOPS 5

sem_t semaphores[THREADS];

class HelloRunnable: public Poco::Runnable {
public:
    HelloRunnable(unsigned int index) {
        _index = index;
        // Seed random generator
        timeval time;
        gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
        srand(time.tv_usec * time.tv_sec);
    }

    virtual void run() {
        for (unsigned int loop = 0; loop < LOOPS; ++loop) {
            // Wait
            sem_wait(&semaphores[_index]);
            // Sleep random time
            int sleep = rand() % 100000;
            usleep(sleep);
            // Output
            std::cout << "Hello, world! This is thread " << _index
                    << " in loop " << loop << " I slept for " << sleep << "µS"
                    << std::endl;
            // Unlock next thread
            sem_post(&semaphores[(_index + 1) % THREADS]);
        }
        return;
    }
private:
    unsigned int _index;
};

int main() {
    HelloRunnable *runnables[THREADS];
    Poco::Thread *threads[THREADS];

    // Initialize semaphores and create threads and runnables
    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < THREADS; ++index) {
        sem_init(&semaphores[index], 0, index ? 0 : 1);
        threads[index] = new Poco::Thread();
        runnables[index] = new HelloRunnable(index);
    }

    // Start threads
    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < THREADS; ++index) {
        threads[index]->start(*runnables[index]);
    }

    // Wait for all threads to finish
    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < THREADS; ++index) {
        threads[index]->join();
    }

    // Cleanup
    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < THREADS; ++index) {
        free(runnables[index]);
        free(threads[index]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```